# Are broad, unspecific questions about entire topic areas preferred over specific questions related to concrete problems?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

In particular, I am referring to [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061274/why-index-was-out-of-range-error-for-lists-but-not-for-arrays-in-c-sharp) that ended up deleted by its owner, and [my attempt to save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061679/why-index-was-out-of-range-error-for-lists-but-not-for-arrays-in-c-sharp), because I think it was a legitimate question.

The underlying issue described in the question is that its original author did not understand the difference between passing `x` in

```
new int[x]
```

and

```
new List<int>(x)
```

As a symptom of that lack of understanding, an `IndexOutOfRangeException` was observed.

The original question was closed by [Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3010968/selman22) and my revival of the question was closed by [Henk Holtermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman). Both close votes were single votes (i.e. without any confirming votes of other users), and both votes were *duplicate* votes pointing to [*What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/20940980).

The linked question and its community wiki answer focuses on what an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is. It briefly touches upon the [`List<T>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but does not even mention that `List<T>` has a constructor that accepts an initial capacity.

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061679/why-index-was-out-of-range-error-for-lists-but-not-for-arrays-in-c-sharp#comment57848575_35061679), Henk suggests that

> Answers about this should be concentrated under the canonical question.

However, to me, it is absolutely not clear what "this" is. The two closed questions are *not* about `IndexOutOfRangeException` as such. They could just as well have been about `Length` vs. `Count`, dealing with the same underlying problem of misunderstanding the difference between the list's capacity argument and the array's size-based initialization.

As such, by editing the respective information into the (already quite lengthy) community wiki answer, we transform the so-called canonical question into *What is IndexOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it? And what are all the different cases in which it might appear?*

Without any doubt, such a question would be closed as *too broad*, if asked directly like that.

**Is it really desirable to grow canonical answers into all directions rather than staying focused, in a way that such canonical answers eventually rival a comprehensive manual like MSDN?**

Or, differently put:

**Should canonical answers still focus on particular questions, or should they amass any kinds of vaguely related information to the topic at hand, with the expectation that any slightly related future questions are duplicates because their answers can be somehow deduced from the canonical answer?**

Comment: Why did you repost it? What's the plan if the original is undeleted?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I started to write an explanation as an answer, and by the time I had finished it, the owner of the original question had deleted the question, and another user had closed it. The deletion by the owner indicated to me that the owner had lost interest in pursuing this question, while it also prevented me of stating my points against the close vote in a comment. Thus, the chances of the question ever being reopened seemed low, while at the same time I didn't want to see my effort and time of explaining the issue wasted. ...

Comment: ... Indeed, maybe not the best way to handle this situation. But after already spending some effort possibly in vain (and it's not the first time I had just written what I thought was a helpful answer, just to find out the question had just been closed and/or deleted and thus doesn't accept any new answers), I had little motivation of adding even more effort with uncertain value by 1) storing my answer in a place where I find it again, and 2) observing the original question for the off-chance it ever gets re-opened, and 3) re-posting my stored answer then, based on the thin hope that ...

Comment: ... no other answer has been accepted already and my answer remains unnoticed/unread and hence useless below other, higher voted answers.

Comment: I've recently had the same problem with a massive question, one part of which was "I'm getting a null reference exception" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102510/c-sharp-class-returns-null-object . Ironically, the person who marked it as a dupe actually answered my specific question in the comments, an answer unrelated to the dupe target and not found in any of the answers there. If I can't ask and answer/have answered specific questions, what then is the purpose of SO? Should I just post books worth of information to Wikipedia and tell developers to figure it out themselves?

Answer (score 19):

Well, there's an awful lot of text in the dupe target, isn't there?

To derive a proper answer to [Why "Index was out of range" exception for List<T> but not for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061679/why-index-was-out-of-range-error-for-lists-but-not-for-arrays-in-c-sharp) from the canonical [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/20940980), one would first have to read the entire thing, compare and contrast the differences in behavior between arrays and lists, and then tease out those parts of the behaviors that are germane.

That's a lot of work for an (arguably unique) question that could have received a short, specific answer tailored to the OP's specific problem instead.

I see some potential issues with using [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/20940980)  as a routine dupe target.  For starters, it was originally intended to be directed at people who don't understand the fundamental reasons why they're getting the error in the first place, yet it contains language that only an experienced programmer would understand.  It's certainly comprehensive, but it asks a lot of someone who is struggling with the basic concept of index bounds.

That said, the author of the original [Why "Index was out of range" exception for List<T> but not for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061679/why-index-was-out-of-range-error-for-lists-but-not-for-arrays-in-c-sharp) already had a fundamental understanding of index boundaries, yet we directed him to the canonical question anyway.

In other words, we took [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/20940980) from what should have been a very simple answer to a very simple question that people ask all the time, and made it into a tome.

I don't necessarily have a problem with that; in fact, I like the way [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940980/102937) starts really simple and gradually gets progressively more advanced.  What I disagree with is the knee jerk reaction to the original [Why "Index was out of range" exception for List<T> but not for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061679/why-index-was-out-of-range-error-for-lists-but-not-for-arrays-in-c-sharp), which, in effect, was *"Everything you ever wanted to know about IndexOutOfRangeException is [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-indexoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/20940980); go figure it out for yourself."*

I think we need to be a little more discerning than that.

Comment: Fully agree. Great answer.

Comment: I fully agree with this statement, and I may have exaggerated in my answer. My reaction was mainly directed at the way _this_ question is phrased. The premise of this question's title and the bold parts is simply wrong, and does not apply to the canonical Q&A it is about.

Comment: @Robert: I think now I am able to better comprehend what you are trying to say here. Thank you for this. However, I see that you have re-opened [(this question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061679) considering it to be an original question. As I understand from your logic above, I now feel [(that being the original question)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35061274/) should've been re-opened in the stead. Alternatively, the dupe target of that original question could be changed to this one. Am I right, or am I still not getting it?

Comment: @Abhitalks: It's too late for that.  All of the answers, commentary, etc. are now attached to the new question.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

1. People tired of seeing 'easy' questions that have to do with basic concepts are closing questions so people will be discouraged from asking basic questions.
2. Because the error is the same (even if the fix listed is too long/vague to be helpful), they can do so with relative ease.

This behavior was somewhat encouraged by a [liberal reading of Joel's thoughts on the subject](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), but they're missing a few key points:

> If you're going to close a user's question as a duplicate, it has to be a real duplicate. For example, if a user asks, "What does the IP address 128.0.1.1/24 mean?" it's OK to close that as a duplicate of a more general question like "What do IP addresses of the form a.b.c.d/e mean?" **But it's not OK to close it as a duplicate of a twenty-seven page guide to netmasks.** That's the moral equivalent of saying "RTFM." Stack Overflow is not meant to be a library of reference manuals. It's supposed to contain the same information as a library of reference manuals, in the form of millions of questions and answers. (emphasis added)

With how the 'canonical' answers have evolved into a very large set of instructions that may or may not solve the individual's specific problems, it's easy to see that these close-dupes are becoming ways to dismiss the OP with "RTFM", and that's not OK.

So to answer your question:

So long as the canonical answer answers the OP's problem easily (with a minimum amount of effort required to understand the answer), then *yes*, it's OK to close them as a duplicate of the canonical answer.

If it's not easy (or it's buried because we made that canonical answer into a manual), then the existing policy is *not to close it as a duplicate*, and take the time and answer the OP's question in way that's easy to find (either for the OP or for a search via Google).

Comment: So because the answers to the canonical _"What is a NullReferenceException / IndexOutOfRangeException"_ questions have become too large (i.e. more than a few paragraphs) by trying to be complete, including debugging hints, background and whatnot, they're unsuitable as duplicate targets? So what should we do with the twenty-odd questions that get asked about those exceptions per day, just start answering them again? Note that there's an army of sub-10K rep users that are doing that anyway.

Comment: What OP of that question was linked to is not a "twenty-seven page guide to netmasks". It is a canonical answer to _"What is an IndexOutOfRangeException"_, starting with the meaning of the exception and deep-diving into the possible causes. The question we're talking about here, as asked, even when edited in any wat that still contains the original meaning, is _not_ another "canonical", it's just plain misunderstanding and lack of debugging. Again: should we just answer each iteration of questions like this?

Comment: The answer to their question is in the first sentence of that answer. The rest of the answer exists of debugging hints. Last time: so we should just answer every variation of _"What is an IndexOutOfRangeException"_, because you deem this not a suitable canonical Q&A?

Comment: @CodeCaster If you can read Joel Spolsky's post and honestly believe that doesn't apply to how the canonical answer is laid out; I don't think we have enough in common to actually have a debate on this issue.

Comment: @george: I am confused now as to what constitutes a good canon?! An answer which covers all possible causes of an *index out of bounds* or an answer which just covers one aspect about an array and leaves out derivatives for a dozen other questions to be asked on the same underlying cause?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've always viewed canonical questions as a way to help someone with research they should have already done themselves.  Sure, if the answer to their specific question is buried in mounds of superfluous text, it's not a duplicate, but the problems highlighted by a NullReferenceException or IndexOutOfRangeException are not remarkable, and the solutions are always the same.  The folks who repeatedly ask such questions lack a basic understanding of the concept; a good canonical question should provide that understanding.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The problem is when we indiscriminately close every problem that mentions that error as a duplicate; as you write in your answer, the canonical answer becomes so big that it's hard to figure out the specific answer you need to solve your problem. Once we've crossed that bridge, we've gone too far.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is, in my opinion, invalid. The duplicates we're talking about here (*"What is a IndexOutOfRangeException/NullReferenceException"*) are not "broad and growing in all directions". They perfectly explain the cause of those very common exceptions, in the first sentence of their answer. They then continue to explain common causes, debugging hints and workarounds for those exceptions.

Those questions are used of duplicate targets of questions that generally should be closed anyway. By closing as a duplicate of such canonicals, you're giving OP pointers to do more debugging, so they can actually ask a good question.

The question at hand *could* be interesting, but that would require a massive rewrite. It will then come down to this:

> Why does `var list = new List<string>(5)` still throw an IndexOutOfRangeException at `list[0]`?

That will show that the OP actually did some debugging, knows where the problem is and ask a clear, specific and answerable question that will be useful for others. It then will be a very narrowly-scoped question that in turn can become a canonical question, explaining the difference between capacity and contents of lists.

I even wouldn't be surprised if that question already exists. If so, would you agree that *that* would be a suitable duplicate target?

By answering every variation of those dreaded exceptions where in the end the answer is the same, we would be reducing the average answer quality even more, spreading out knowledge over way too many answers, causing later searchers to have to wade through even more crap before finding an answer that actually explains their problem.

If we're not allowed to close zero-effort or zero-understanding questions as duplicates of canonical Q&As that very thoroughly and understandably explain the root cause and solutions because "Then OP has to read too much", I'll stop all my efforts to do some quality control and answer every question that I see.

Comment: *...visibly lack research effort* is a reason to downvote, not close.

Comment: I don't believe we have enough in common to actually have a debate on this issue.

Comment: I disagree with two major points in your answer: First, you say "They perfectly explain the cause of those very common exceptions, in the first sentence of their answer." - however, the first sentence in said answer reads: "This exception means that you're trying to access a collection item by index, using an invalid index." Obviously, the original asker of the question was sure they *were* using a valid index. Hence, the question is not answered in the sentence and your thus-related premise appears false. Second, you speak about a "massive rewrite" to transform the question into ...

Comment: ... *Why does var list = new List<string>(5) still throw an IndexOutOfRangeException at list[0]?*. Interestingly, this is essentially what I understand the question as already in its current form. I fail to see the "massive rewrite" requiring difference between your (admittedly a bit more well-phrased) version and "why the Out of Range error occurred for the List type and not for the array?" With that said, the claim that "var list = new List<string>(5) [throws] an IndexOutOfRangeException" from your version is actually somewhat inaccurate, given that this statement throws nothing.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper it isn't the first OP who thinks they're doing it right but they aren't. That's no problem, but please read the paragraph after my "revised" question again. Would you mind me editing your reposted question into something _I_ think would properly and readably explain the problem?

Comment: *"If we're not allowed to close zero-effort or zero-understanding questions as duplicates of canonical Q&As"...* That's just it. Zero effort is not a reason to close. If you're closing something because they didn't spend any effort on their question, you're fighting an uphill battle that you'll lose because it'll get flagged for moderator attention, and we'll be forced to agree with the OP that zero-effort or zero research *is not a reason to close a question*.  Downvote until your heart's content. But if you're closing as a duplicate in lieu of downvoting, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @George, alright. I know that, and I agree with that. I should have phrased that differently. Yet if a question is closable for any reason, but a canonical dupe _may_ help the OP further based on the content of the question, if only by the mentioned debugging hints, is it fine to close as duplicate? Or should one then still close the appropriate reason (e.g. offtopic - not enough info or code), and perhaps link to the dupe in a comment? Or should I search whether that's been asked before, and if not ask my own question about that? ;-)

Comment: It's definitely better if you ask a meta question about this; as I can't really go into sufficient detail in a comment to give you a better understanding of how we view things; but should you not decide  to do that: If a question is closable, close it for the reason that most applies. Unless the dupe target is going to solve their immediate problem, *don't close it as a duplicate*. It's akin to leaving a comment telling them to RTFM; and it won't help them. It'll make you feel better, definitely, but it won't actually help them.

Comment: @George sure, maybe I will. In the meantime _then_ I hope the "Change your close-vote after the question is edited" feature will be implemented soon, if ever.

Comment: Zero effort and zero understanding are *certainly* reasons to close a question. I don't know if that policy has changed or something, but if it has, it needs to change back. They may not be reasons to close a question as a duplicate, but pick one of the other close reasons. And downvote. If we can't close questions that are utter crap, this site has completely gone down the tubes and *with endorsement from the moderators*.

Comment: @CodyGray that's never been an official policy. Some people tried to turn the "minimal understanding of the problem being solved" close reason into that, so SE inc had to nuke that close reason.

Comment: Too bad we're nuking close reasons instead of nuking bad questions.