# What should be done with this specific highly upvoted question asking how to debug a Node.js application?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, canonical

The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911015/how-do-i-debug-node-js-applications) has gathered a couple hundred thousand views and more than 800 upvotes:

> ## How do I debug Node.js applications?
>
> How do I debug a Node.js server application?
>
> Right now I'm mostly using *alert debugging* with print statements
> like this:
>
> ```
> sys.puts(sys.inspect(someVariable));
> ```
>
> There must be a better way to debug. I know that [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)
> has a command-line debugger. Is this debugger available for Node.js as
> well?

Most answers are very short tool recommendations and would be considered VLQ today.
There is however some very interesting information in there.

I do not think keeping this question open for more answers will bring any good.
It will only attract more VLQ and  borderline spam.

In the spirit of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) we could keep [this link aggregating answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512303/4174897) as community wiki and merge/delete the others. The question would be edited to reflect its tool rec nature and locked to prevent more answers to be posted.

Should this question stay in its current state?
If not, what should be done with it?

---

I brought this discussion to Meta instead of immediately sending it to the queue with a vote since it's an old, highly-upvoted post. I think we should decide as a community what happens next.
Thus, please refrain from close-voting the question, delete-voting it or its answers until consensus is achieved.

Comment: Seems like a reaonable candidate for a Historical Lock.

Comment: The thing is, it won't get anymore votes if it's frozen

Comment: This question is fine, and should not be closed or deleted or locked.

Comment: @george the question is a list of tools, those types of questions are off topic because of the maintainability aspect. I would love to see something from the node community about whether or not they are actively maintaining it, but it definitely isn't a good Q&A in its current form. The answers are mostly lacking in explanation, and I wouldn't be surprised to find out that some of the recommended tools are obsolete. I don't think that leaving it in its current form is wise.

Comment: @Tim Where would you rather find a list of Node debugger tools and how to use them? A blog post from 2009? A poorly maintained wiki on some third party site that hasn't been updated in 2013? StackOverflow is the best place for it, even if the question is off-topic today.

Comment: @user5867440 the node.js site and manual ;)

Comment: @Gimby Am I going to find a debugging tutorial for Javascript in the EMCAScript specification?

Comment: @user5867440 I'm guessing that you were referring to me as I'm the only one commenting here whose name starts with ti, I wouldn't be opposed to keeping the question around if it was made community wiki and histo-locked, and if all of the answers were edited up to par, remains bing any that were obsolete, and if the node community was willing to maintain it. In its current form it is just a broken window.

Comment: @TinyGiant The question isn't asking for a list of tools, it's asking how to debug node.js applications; just because a tool fits that purpose *doesn't mean the question is off topic*.

Comment: @george I didn't say it was a tool request, I said it was a list question, which is what it is. I'm on my phone right now so I'm not going to look for the reference, but IIRC list questions are considered bad questions. If nothing else it is too broad.

Comment: @TinyGiant If you can quote the part of the question that's asking for a list, let me know. I've read it a few times and can't find the part that says, "I'm looking for a list of tools to debug Node.js".

Comment: @George, as I said, it is Too Broad if nothing else, which can be seen by the large number of answers it has received. I don't really want to close it, but I also don't think it should be left as it is in its current form after it has been brought to our attention. Forget the closing and histo-locking, convert the whole thing to community wiki, expand upon the answers which are currently lacking in explanation, and remove any obsolete answers. (I'm not saying that you should do this, besides the cw, but as a community, we should do *something* with it)

Comment: I mean, if I asked how to debug JavaScript today, it would probably be closed within a minute or two as Too Broad.

Comment: @user5867440 - YMCAScript, for what it's worth.

Comment: @user5867440 javascript is a general purpose language, nodejs is very different

Comment: Why not canonicalise it? We're talking about [canonicalising C# questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315913/), why not these too? JS and node are some of SO's most popular tags

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is an interesting question that provides, at least, some value in sharing resources on how to debug Node.js applications. I assume when it was asked it was an acceptable question. If it were asked now (worded exactly the same way), it wouldn't surprise me to see it closed in short order as too broad.

The too broad close reason states (emphasis mine):

> There are either **too many** possible answers, or good answers would be
>   **too long** for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

"How do I debug X?" is a pretty broad question, either in the sense of "teach me how to debug" or "what should I use to debug?".

Everyone is going to have their own style and tool preference. Logging to the console, alerts, any of a hundred tools, all are valid answers.  And you could argue all day about which one is "better".

Most of the questions I see on this site are usually about how to solve a problem within some given constraints. And while everyone could come up with their own solution, many of the answers will be similar. And we can objectively check that a solution works or doesn't. This question doesn't have much in terms of constraints. There's also no way to check the "workingness" of a solution. They all work for someone. And there isn't a terribly objective way of saying "this is better because it avoids SQL injection attacks (or what have you)" or "this works but trades speed for memory". It's more of "this is what I use and I like it because A, B, C."

---

Assuming I'm not off my rocker about this being closed if asked today, the question still stands about what to do with it. My vote is for a historical lock and / or possibly a wiki answer to keep information gathered and up to date. It is a question that was (presumably) fine back in the day, but is not a good example of an acceptable question now.

Comment: I don't think that a histo-lock is a good idea because that would remove any possibility of maintaining the list. Also, a single wiki answer isn't a good idea because it would be unwieldy and you wouldn't be able to easily tell which tool was being voted for, however, if the whole thing was converted to community wiki, it would be a lot easier to maintain and future answers would all be community wiki, so it would deter users who are just looking for rep from posting low quality answers.

Comment: @TinyGiant I like that idea better.  I forgot that histo-locking makes it impossible to edit.  Wiki-ing the whole thing is something I'm not sure I've seen before, but if that is an accurate description, I'm all for it.

Comment: @TinyGiant The only thing I do like about the histo-lock tho is the message that "we are keeping this for historical significance, but don't post anything like this now".  I'm guessing making the whole thing a CW won't do that, right?

Comment: No, it wont. But there's nothing stopping you from making your own banner using a blockquote.

Comment: @TinyGiant True, but it wouldn't be hard to edit out either.  Not sure how big of a deal that is and if it is worth worrying about at all.

Comment: Yeah, but that's why I would like to see if the node community is willing to maintain the Q&A, it isn't really something that we can fix once then leave alone. Questions like this need active maintenance and monitoring for activity.

Comment: I'd say that all canonical questions are on the verge of being too broad, but that's not a bad thing. "too broad" is a close reason for unreasonable requests, as soon as someone answers (in a long and detailed post) it only becomes really useful (as you can judge from the view counts as well). And it's definitely on-topic.

Answer (score 10):

Votes are the least of concern when it comes to historical lock. If you historical lock, none of the posts can be ***edited*** which means the answers can not be improved. This is bad if visitors come upon the question and follow advice for a post that's outdated, especially for a technology that's relatively recent (2009). Now if the question were asking "What are the best debuggers for Win95?" then the information would certainly be of no use to **most** people so a historical lock would be appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

This is a valid question for Stack Overflow and meets our criteria for staying open.

- It's not **Too Broad**: Any answer to the question "How do I debug in Node.js" is answerable in a few paragraphs
- It's not **Primarily Opinion-Based**: There is no expectation that the answer to "How do I debug Node.js applications?" will involve any opinion; rather it is a factual event. Either you can or you cannot debug Node.js applications; there is no opinion involved.  Had the OP asked, "What's the best way to debug Node.js applications?", that would be a warning flag (and should result in an edit changing the scope of the question).
- It's **not a duplicate** of any other question; it has the highest number of views, votes, most complete answers.
- It's not asking for **off-site resources**:  The OP mentions a resource in his question, but only as a reference point; "This is how I do it currently".  It's entirely possible that the answer will *not involve* any external resources.
- It's a **programming question**: Node.js is a developer's server-side framework for developing JavaScript applications: The question has no bearing or relevance outside of the programmer community

So regardless of its current state, or the answers its attracted, *or anything else*, it meets our criteria for staying open. That's probably why it hasn't been closed yet; there's no suitable criteria for closing it.

To address the fact that a lot of answers are off site resource recommendations:

It's OK to give an answer that involves an offsite resource; it's *not OK* to ask a question to solicit off-site resources. See the difference?  A good answer that involves an off site resource references the following:

- What is this thing you're talking about?
- Where do I install it?
- How do I install it?
- How do I use this thing to solve *the exact problem I have in my question*?
- Are you affiliated with this thing in any way, shape, or form?

The state of Node.js has made the possible existence of a lot of answers; not the state of the problem itself; that's a huge difference in whether the question is Too Broad: What's the scope of the activity being discussed?  Debugging Node.js is a very narrow activity; either I can or I can't, and it's an activity that I'd expect to have to learn how to do, and it's not situational in nature (it doesn't depend on my current working conditions).

So in short: The question should stay open, unlocked, and non-Community Wiki.  At best we could make a "Wiki answer" lock if we want to; but it's not required and should only be done so on request.

Comment: So if a question can have 50 different answers it is not too broad?

Comment: @NathanOliver I could list 10 ways to a simple task in Perl; and I'd wager some could come up with many more; but that doesn't mean any question about a specific task in perl is too broad.

Comment: I just threw out 50 as an example.  The too broad close vote reason has as the first sentence *There are either too many possible answers*. IMHO  several or more ways is to many and qualifies as too broad.

Comment: Also, I looked through it's history. it's only had *one* close vote in its entire history.

Comment: I have left it alone as it does not affect me.  Node people seem to like it so I am letting them and others deal with it.  I would not appreciate people getting rid of *The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List* as the C++ community has decided we want it.

Comment: I never said it has to be closed.  I just do not agree with you that a question that can be answered with 32 answers does not qualify for too broad.

Comment: @NathanOliver That makes sense. Keep in mind though that if a question is too broad; then it should be closed. The C++ community had to fight hard to keep their list question.  But we also have yet to find 5 people willing to close this question as too broad.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Not sure if it had any impact, but I did ask in my question not to vote to close until community consensus is achieved.

Comment: This question is perfectly valid - because finding the answer isn't straight forward. The `node-inspector` answer is very short because that's all the user needs to know. With that clue, finding the rest of the information becomes easy, but you need to know to look for the inspector. I myself have used this answer before and appreciated it.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth It would be better if that answer were more fleshed out; showed how to use node-inspector; what it would look like when it was in use, how to add breakpoints, etc.

Comment: The only thing about the question that irks me a little is the last attached *"Is this debugger available for Node.js as well?"* follow-up question. That makes it look like a google-it-for-me type of question mixed with a tool request which distracts from the actual source question asked.

Comment: Strongly disagree with this. The question is not only _very_ broad, it is also on the border of tool recommendations. Had this question been asked today, it would probably have been down-voted to oblivion and closed within 10 minutes. "Historical lock" seems like appropriate action if you want to keep the income the question generates through traffic.

Comment: @Lundin: There is no rule against recommending a tool in an answer.  The rule is that a question must not demand that answers recommend a tool.  The question should instead focus on the task at hand and let experts explain whether it is possible using only built-in features, and what the pros and cons are for going the built-in route or using extra tools/libraries.

Comment: Broadness in answers can be extremely temporal. Consider an example where, initially, there might be just one answer. In seeing that, other developers realize there's a market and create 20 new answers. Now there are 21. Those are all branched 10 times for specialization. Now there are hundreds of answers... The answer changes over time... that's exactly what a wiki is for. IMO, a bigger, general problem on SO is it needs to handle slowly morphing answers better. Or, in this specific case, list-style answers that will change over time but are very valuable.

Comment: George - thanks for posting this answer, thereby putting meat on the bones of your earlier comments. (I'm referring mainly to the points re what a tool rec answer should contain to be _good_.) I'd like to see this summation as part of the FAQ, or otherwise generalized. I see many questions of this ilk, and agree that the questions themselves aren't the problem, rather it's the presence of weak, link-only or purely promotional answers that rankles. Being able to point those authors to this list would help improve the helpfulness of their answers, and may help cull the poorest ones.

Comment: ... maybe as part of [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after much thought and consideration, here are the suggested options which I disagree with, and why I think they are bad ideas:

- **Closure**. This would be a way of stopping new low-quality answers from being posted, but it isn't a viable option because it will just be reopened again.
- **Histo-lock**. This isn't a viable option because it would disallow further maintenance of the question and its answers.

That leaves us with one final option, which seems like the best course of action:

### Community Wiki

We make the question and all of its answers Community Wiki. This has a few benefits:

- It discourages future low-quality answers because no rep can be gained by posting a new answer (all new answers will also be Community Wiki).
- It allows for more in-depth maintenance of the question and its answers as we would no longer have to worry about "putting words in the authors mouths".

After it is made Community Wiki we can:

- Edit the question, if necessary.
- Edit all of the useful answers to contain an explanation of the solution, an example of its use, and references to the relevant documentation.
- Delete any useless answers.

After all of this is said and done, it is up to the node community to further maintain the question and its answers.

Comment: Downvoters care to explain why they disagree?

Comment: Do nothing is also an option.

Comment: That is such a bad option, I don't consider it to be an option.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The current state of the question is not acceptable for something with such a large audience and SEO juice. While some answers are really amazing, many also are two-liners "try this tool" recommendations. A clean-up is needed to remove all VLQ posts, and turning the whole thing into CW would allow for way easier maintenance and improvements over time. Many tools exist to debug Node.js and this question has become one of the main place to look at for them. The community should take hold of the while thing and take care of it.